# Remove json key from response in jmeter and feed processed response as request to next sampler

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, beanshell, jsr223

I have a sampler 1 which generates response like

```
{ ....... updatedAt: dateAndtime, createdAt: datetime}
```

Now this response i have to process by removing updatedAt , createdAt key, values and then feed same as request body to next sampler. Could any one help , how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

   response.remove('updatedAt')
   response.remove('createdAt')

   vars.put('request', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(response).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. Refer the amended request value as `${request}` later on where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)